# nested polymorphism in scala

Tags: scala, polymorphism, implicit

I need an implicit class with a method that lets me merge any immutable map types (`<: Map`) that may have duplicate keys & polymorphic values. I can't figure out to get the implicit class to use nested polymorphic types and work implicitly (something like `A <: Map[_, B], B <: Combinable[B]`).

I can get it to work on all Map types...  or on polymorphic values...  but not both.  I can't figure out how to combine into one implicit class without the error that it can't find the method in the implicit class.

So for example...

```
trait Combinable[A] {
  this: A =>

  def combine(that: A): A

  def combine(that: Option[A]): A = that match {
    case Some(a) => this combine a
    case None => this
  }
}
```

So let's say I have a class...

```
case class Meta(???) extends Combinable[Meta] {
  def combine(that: Meta): Meta = ???
}
```

Now if I have a standard immutable `Map`, it's a cinch...  works great.

```
implicit class CombinableMaps[A <: Combinable[A]](val m1: Map[String, A]) {
  def mergeMaps(m2: Map[String, A]): Map[String, A] = {  
    m1 ++
    m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v combine m1.get(k)) }
  }.asInstanceOf[Map[String, A]]
}
```

But what if I want it to also work on `TreeMap`s and `SortedMap`s and whatever else?

```
implicit class CombinableMaps[B <: Combinable[B], A <: Map[String,B]](val m1: A) {
  def mergeMaps(m2: A): A = {  
    m1 ++
    m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v combine m1.get(k)) }
  }.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

This compiles without an error, but when I try using the `mergeMap` method it throws `error: value mergeMaps is not a member of Map[String,Meta]`.

I tried a variation where `B` was a type passed to `A` like `A[B]`...  again, compiled (if I imported `scala.language.higherKinds`) but didn't get applied.

Is this kind of nested polymorphism allowed?  I can't even figure out what term to search for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Besides **@francoisr**'s proposal where your approach with F-bounded polymorphism (`B <: Combinable[B]`) is proposed to be replaced with ad hoc polymorphism (`Combinable` becomes a type class), you can also try to replace bounds with implicit constraints. Try to replace

```
implicit class CombinableMaps[B <: Combinable[B], A <: Map[String, B]](val m1: A) {
  def mergeMaps(m2: A): A = {  
    m1 ++
    m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v combine m1.get(k)) }
  }.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

with

```
implicit class CombinableMaps[A, B](val m1: A)(implicit
  ev: A <:< Map[String, B],
  ev1: B <:< Combinable[B]
) {
  def mergeMaps(m2: A): A = {
    m1 ++
      m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v combine m1.get(k)) }
  }.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

or just

```
implicit class CombinableMaps[A, B <: Combinable[B]](val m1: A)(implicit
  ev: A <:< Map[String,B]
) {
  def mergeMaps(m2: A): A = {
    m1 ++
      m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v combine m1.get(k)) }
  }.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

Then `Map("a" -> Meta(1), "b" -> Meta(2)).mergeMaps(Map("c" -> Meta(3), "d" -> Meta(4)))` compiles [[scastie]](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/PQ1U5eS3Tky4pwmShrJoGA)

Also I propose to remove this ugly `asInstanceOf[A]` [[scastie]](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/gEvU8nXfReGVlnpPEyxQGg)

```
import scala.collection.immutable.MapOps

implicit class CombinableMaps[A, B <: Combinable[B], 
                              CC[K,+V] <: MapOps[K, V, CC, _]](val m1: A)(implicit
  ev0: A => CC[String, B],
  ev2: CC[String, B] => A,
) {
  def mergeMaps(m2: A): A = {
    m1 ++
      m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v combine m1.get(k)) }
  }
}
```

or just

```
implicit class CombinableMaps[B <: Combinable[B], 
                              CC[K,+V] <: MapOps[K, V, CC, _]
                             ](val m1: CC[String, B]){
  def mergeMaps(m2: CC[String, B]): CC[String, B] = {
    m1 ++
      m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> (v combine m1.get(k)) }
  }
}
```

Comment: Just curious: is there any upside to using this rather than higher-kinded types? Not saying this is any worse at all, I just want to see if there are cases where this approach is preferable.

Comment: @francoisr Well, f-bounds vs. type classes are well known competing approaches https://tpolecat.github.io/2015/04/29/f-bounds.html There's no universal advantage. Type classes are a little more flexible if you're interested in flexibility. F-bounds are a little more rigid if you're interested in rigidity. My first fix was just a minimal fix to OP's code. Please notice my second fix. I removed `asInstanceOf`.

Comment: @francoisr note that **F-Bound** is also more fragile, you can easily break it. Also, this is just a '*Semigroup**.

Comment: @francoisr So, introducing a higher-kinded types is a good idea (since, as we can see, `Map` ops like `++` are defined in such way). Just you additionally replaced f-bounded `Combinable` with a type class and my previous comment was about this.

Comment: why does `MapOps` eliminate the need for `implicit ev0, ev2` but `Map` needs either that or my clumsy `AsInstanceOf[]`?  Sadly, i'm on scala 2.11.8, so no MapOps, but you've given me so much good stuff here, that's not a problem.

Comment: @kmh Because if `A = CC[String, B]` then `A => CC[String, B]`, `CC[String, B] => A` are just `A => A` and such implicit is in a scope automatically: `def test[A]: Unit = { implicitly[A => A] }` compiles.

Answer (score 4):

The key to solving your issue is to not try to infer `A` immediately. Even something as simple will trip the type inference:

```
class Foo[B, A <: Map[String, B]](val a: A)
new Foo(Map("foo" -> 42))

inferred type arguments [Nothing,scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]] do not conform to value 's type parameter bounds [B,A <: Map[String,B]]

type mismatch;
 found   : scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int]
 required: A
```

This is because type inference works in "layers": it resolves both `A` and `B` before it can inspect the "insides" of `A`. The solution is to define A differently:

```
class Foo[B, A[X] <: Map[String, X]](val a: A[B])
new Foo(Map("foo" -> 42))
```

Let's look at your problem now. Your `Combinable` trait would typically be replaced by a type class so that you don't have to extend `Combinable` on every type `A` you would need to combine. You can just implicitly provide the `Combinable` implicitly for every type you need it. This is entirely optional, you could choose to stick with your trait if you prefer that.

```
trait Combinable[A] {
  def combine(first: A, second: A): A
  def combine(first: A, second: Option[A]): A = second match {
    case Some(a) => combine(first, a)
    case None => first
  }
}

case class Meta(x: Int)
object Meta {
  implicit val combinableInstance: Combinable[Meta] = (first, second) => Meta(first.x + second.x)
}


implicit class CombinableMaps[B : Combinable, A[X] <: Map[String,X]](val m1: A[B]) {
  def mergeMaps(m2: A[B]): A[B] = {  
    m1 ++
    m2.map { case (k,v) => k -> implicitly[Combinable[B]].combine(v,m1.get(k)) }
  }.asInstanceOf[A[B]]
}

import collection.immutable.TreeMap
val m = TreeMap("foo" -> Meta(42), "bar" -> Meta(43))
val m2 = TreeMap("bar" -> Meta(43))
val m3: TreeMap[String,Meta] = m.mergeMaps(m2)
```

Comment: thanks @francoisr...  you guys both gave me so much good stuff to learn about, had never seen ad-hoc polymorphism or type classes before, as well as other stuff.  I have a lot to learn.  Thank you.